# Insert Element in Ckinline

Tags: cross-browser, ckeditor, element, cursor-position

i've tried to insert element in ckinlne editor's current cursor position.
Is there any methods to insert Element in ckinline div's current cursor position?

Comment: You need to add some more information to your question such as version of CKEditor, bits of code you have already tried etc. The more information you provide, the more likely you will get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. Replace editor1 with your editor id in the example below:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml( '<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>' );
```

That example is from the official documentation at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml